# Back-referencing in LaTeX

Tags: cross-referencing, back-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Usage of table/figures shown in caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/usage-of-table-figures-shown-in-caption)

Is there any way to make back-references, outside bibtex, so that by using something like `\backref` LaTeX would show where there are references to an item? For instance:

```
...
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{1} Something. Referenced by [\backref].
\item \label{2} Something else. Referencing [\ref{1}].
\end{enumerate}
...
```

Outputting something like this:

> 1. Something. Referenced by [2].
> 2. Something else. Referencing [1].

---

Well, it will be useful for genealogical texts, where each item is a family, and each subitem a person. When the person marries, I can refer to what family he/she is from, but it would be useful to see to what family he/she belongs also. Perhaps an example will help ; ) :

```
\begin{enumerate}

\item \label{f:1} John and Mary had:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{p:1} James
    \end{enumerate}

\item \label{f:2} Bruce and Alina had:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{p:2} Elisabeth
    \end{enumerate}

\item \label{f:3} James [\ref{p:1}] and Elisabeth [\ref{p:2}] married.

\end{enumerate}
```

The `\backref` would make me able to show were James and Elisabeth married.

Comment: not sure why you want `\backref` here; in this example, `\ref` would seem to do as well since there's a clear `\label` to point to.  `\backref` *does* make sense in a bibliography, where the pointer is to a `\cite` in the body of the text, and there's no other labeling mechanism.  can you provide a more compelling example?

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: @barbara beeton: With the example, it looks like he wants to write in item `p:1` that `James (married \backref{p:1})` and in `p:2` that `Elisabeth (married \backref{p:2})`.

Comment: @RyanReich Reich: not quite. My first example is much more objective, I think : /. With `\ref` I can show James' parents, in my example, but if I want to know where his marriage is, the only way I know is to put `/ref{f:3}` in the item `p:1` by hand, but it should be doable by a command like `\backref`...

Marco Daniel spotted a very similar question, but only with page numbers. I'm trying to understand how it works in the example there.

Comment: @Parjánya: That's what I meant to say :)  In any case, that's what my answer does, so tell me if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this by patching the existing `\ref` command to remember the context in which it was called.  This new version works even if `\ref` is called multiple times on the same label, producing a comma-separated list (no spaces) of numbers.  It has some limitations; for example, the list will produce numbers that look the same no matter what kind of label they belonged to (enumerate, section, and so on).  I think one could add some kind of hook to `\backref` to process the list and improve this situation, but I won't do that unless you say you need it.

This does not work with `hyperref`, for which I apologize.  If you want it, I will go unravel what it does.

This is a complete document; you should copy everything between `\documentclass{article}` and `\begin{document}` into your preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\def\@newbackl@bel#1#2#3{%
 \@ifundefined{#1@#2}%
  {\global\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}}
  {\cs@g@appendpair{#1@#2}{#3}}%
}
% #1 and #2 are each of the form {a}{b}, and the a and b groups are to be concatenated independently.
\def\cs@g@appendpair#1#2{{%
 \edef\first{\csname #1\endcsname}%
 \csxdef{#1}%
  {{\expandafter\@firstoftwo\first,\@firstoftwo#2}%
   {\expandafter\@secondoftwo\first,\@secondoftwo#2}}%
}}

% Patching into the existing commands
\def\newbacklabel{\@newbackl@bel B}
\let\backlabel=\label
\patchcmd\backlabel{\newlabel}{\newbacklabel}{}{}
\let\backref=\ref
\patchcmd\backref{r@#1}{B@#1}{}{}
\let\pagebackref=\pageref
\patchcmd\pagebackref{r@#1}{B@#1}{}{}
\pretocmd\ref{\backlabel{#1}}{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item \label{e:1} Part 1, referenced by part(s) \backref{e:1} on page(s) \pagebackref{e:1}.
 \item \label{e:2} Part 2, referencing part \ref{e:1}
 \item \label{e:3} Part 3, referencing part \ref{e:1}.
\end{enumerate}
\newpage
\section{A section}
\label{s:1}
Here is another reference to part \ref{e:1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, Ryan, thank you a lot! I don't need anything more than this, actually. I think it's a very useful feature, perhaps it deserves to be a package...

Comment: "This does not work with hyperref, for which I apologize. If you want it, I will go unravel what it does." It would be very nice!

Comment: Accompanied by hyperref, \pagebackref now gives only the number of the actual page, nothing more...

Comment: @NikitaKalinin I'm sorry, but I don't hack LaTeX anymore, so I can't honor my offer.

Comment: Can you make this working with \nameref?