# List all pages with a \hyperref to a given label?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, glossaries, back-referencing

In the appendix of my document there's a section called "examples." Each of these examples is relevant to certain sections of the main part of the document. These sections already have `\hyperref`s to their relevant examples.

For each example, I want to create a hyperlinked list of the locations that have hyperrefs to the example -- a la the biblatex `backref=true` option, or glossaries' location list. See the following example:

> section1:
>
> Relevant to example1, example2
>
> section2:
>
> Relevant to example2
>
> example1:
>
> Referenced by section1
>
> example2:
>
> Referenced by section1, section2

Seeing as how this is already doable in both glossaries and bibliographies it must be possible -- I just haven't found a package which provides the functionality.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a compilable document to start with

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/usage-of-table-figures-shown-in-caption

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116046/backreferences-for-equations

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37918/back-referencing-in-latex