# Modifying the definition of label

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I am trying to modify the `\label` command so that it stores the chapter in .aux file in addition to page and `\@currentlabel`. I tried what follows and it does not work.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\def\@newl@bel#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{#1@#2}%
    \relax
    {\gdef \@multiplelabels {%
            \@latex@warning@no@line{There were multiply-defined labels}}%
        \@latex@warning@no@line{Label `#2' multiply defined}}%
    \global\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}}
\def\newlabel{\@newl@bel r}
\@onlypreamble\@newl@bel
\let \@multiplelabels \relax
\def\label#1{\@bsphack
\protected@write\@auxout{}%
{\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}{\thechapter}}}%
\@esphack}
\def\refstepcounter#1{\stepcounter{#1}%
\protected@edef\@currentlabel
{\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}

\def\ref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@firstofthree{#1}}
\def\pageref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@secondofthree{#1}}
\def\chapref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@thirdofthree{#1}}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\chapter{abc}
\begin{theorem}\label{theo}abc\end{theorem}
Theorem \ref{theo} in chapter \chapref{theo}, page \pageref{theo} says that abc.
\end{document}
```

The new command `\chapref` works fine even though it is unrecognized, while `\ref`, and `\pageref` return concatenation of `\@currentlabel` `\thepage` and `thechapter`.

I do not really understand what do the variables in `\@newl@bel` stand for which makes it hard for me to see what I'm doing wrong.

As I have mentioned in the comment, I am interested in solution which does not require any reference packages. I am aware of the nice solution in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39677/identifying-the-section-an-equation-is-in), but I would like to know whether it can be done by modifying the \newlabel.

Comment: I think you should use the `zref` package rather than such weird hacks. Welcome to TeX.SE ... by the way

Comment: I want to do it without any *ref packages.

Comment: Doing it without `ref` packages it is 'dangerous' -- as far as I can see your approach will break a possible use of `hyperref`

Comment: I only need it for a short document which will not require the use of '\hyperref'. It can be viewed as a school experiment.

Comment: Your example doesn't work for me. I get `? ! Undefined control sequence. \@firstofthree `.  Didn't you try your own example?

Comment: It does produce a resulting document for me, however with error - '\chapref' is unrecognized. '\@firstofthree' works fine for me.

Comment: You get an error that the commands `\@firstofthree` (used in `\ref`) and `\@secondofthree` (used in `\pageref`) are undefined and then really wonder that both reference commands don't work as wanted?

Comment: @ajr: I've updated my solution with another version not using any `*ref` related package. There's no need of screwing up `\new@l@bel`, `\refstepcounter`  etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite easy with `zref` and defining a new `chapterprop` property, storing the `\thechapter` then.

The price to pay is `\zref` and `\zlabel` and `\zpageref`, however

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[user]{zref}


\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{chapterprop}{\thechapter}
\zref@addprops{main}{chapterprop}
\newcommand{\chapref}[1]{\zref@extract{#1}{chapterprop}}%\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@thirdofthree{#1}}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\chapter{abc}
\begin{theorem}\zlabel{theo}abc\end{theorem}
Theorem \zref{theo} in chapter \chapref{theo}, page \zpageref{theo} says that abc.
\end{document}
```

**Update** Without any `*ref` - related package, just hacking `\label` and `\ref` and `\pageref` by providing the `\@...ofthree` commands.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter

\def\label#1{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
  {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}{\thechapter}}}%
  \@esphack}

\long\def\@firstofthree#1#2#3{#1}
\long\def\@secondofthree#1#2#3{#2}
%\long\def\@threeofthree#1#2#3{#3}% Is defined in `latex.ltx` already

\def\ref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@firstofthree{#1}}
\def\pageref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname
                                   \@secondofthree{#1}}
\def\chapref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname
                                   \@thirdofthree{#1}}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\chapter{abc}
\begin{theorem}\label{theo}abc\end{theorem}
Theorem \ref{theo} in chapter \chapref{theo}, page \pageref{theo} says that abc.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, adding definitions of "..ofthree" indeed works! For some reason my TeX did not point out that the problem was there.

Comment: @ajr: Most likely because the error was in a earlier part of your code  -- TeX choked on that and did not realize `\@firstof...` etc. were not defined!

Comment: BTW, it's `\@thirdofthree`, not `\@threeofthree`.

Answer (score 3):

Seems your code works after commenting out a few things that are not necessary and adding definitions for `\@firstofthree` and `\@secondofthree`. (`\@thirdoftree` is already defined.)

Your code does break the **hyperref**-package and therefore does only work as long as the **hyperref**-package is not loaded.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@newl@bel[3]{%
  \@ifundefined{#1@#2}%
  \relax
  {%
    \gdef\@multiplelabels{%
      \@latex@warning@no@line{There were multiply-defined labels}%
    }%
    \@latex@warning@no@line{Label `#2' multiply defined}%
  }%
  \global\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}%
}%
%\@onlypreamble\@newl@bel
%\let\@multiplelabels\relax
\renewcommand*\label[1]{%
  \@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout
                  {}%
                  {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}{\thechapter}}}%
  \@esphack
}%
%\def\refstepcounter#1{%
%  \stepcounter{#1}%
%  \protected@edef\@currentlabel
%  {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
%}%
\renewcommand*\ref[1]{%
  \expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@firstofthree{#1}%
}%
\renewcommand*\pageref[1]{%
  \expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@secondofthree{#1}%
}%
\newcommand*\chapref[1]{%
  \expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@thirdofthree{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@firstofthree[3]{#1}%
\newcommand\@secondofthree[3]{#2}%
%\newcommand\@thirdofthree[3]{#3}%
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\chapter{abc}
\begin{theorem}\label{theo}abc\end{theorem}
Theorem \ref{theo} in chapter \chapref{theo}, page \pageref{theo} says that abc.
\end{document}
```

In case you really don't wish to use the **zref**-package I can offer another crude hack which seems not to break the **hyperref**-package:

Redefine/patch the `\label`-command in order to have the `\label`-command patch the `\@currentlabel`-macro in a way leading to `\@currentlabel` expand to two arguments preceeded by a robust command for selecting one of the two arguments, the first argument holding what `\@currentlabel` held before being patched, the second argument holding `\thechapter`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%%\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\My@GetRefArg[2]{#1}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\MyOther@GetRefArg[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\My@saved@currentlabel{}%
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\My@oldlabel=\label
  \renewcommand\label[1]{%
    \@bsphack
    \let\My@saved@currentlabel=\@currentlabel
    \expandafter\def
    \expandafter\@currentlabel
    \expandafter{%
    \expandafter\My@GetRefArg
    \expandafter{%
    \@currentlabel}{\thechapter}}%
    \@esphack
    \My@oldlabel{#1}%
    \@bsphack
    \let\@currentlabel=\My@saved@currentlabel
    \@esphack
  }%
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\chaprefAtNoStar[1]{%
      \begingroup
      \let\My@GetRefArg\MyOther@GetRefArg
      \ref{#1}%
      \endgroup
    }%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\chaprefAtStar[1]{%
      \begingroup
      \let\My@GetRefArg\MyOther@GetRefArg
      \ref*{#1}%
      \endgroup
    }%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\chapref{%
      \@ifstar\chaprefAtStar\chaprefAtNoStar
    }%
  }{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\chapref[1]{%
      \begingroup
      \let\My@GetRefArg\MyOther@GetRefArg
      \ref{#1}%
      \endgroup
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\chapter{abc}
\begin{theorem}\label{theo}abc\end{theorem}
Theorem \ref{theo} in chapter \chapref{theo}, page \pageref{theo} says that abc.
%%
%%Theorem \ref*{theo} in chapter \chapref*{theo}, page \pageref*{theo} says that abc.
\end{document}
```

In case of using **hyperref**, hyperlinks with `\chapref` will not lead to the start of the chapter in question but to the anchor that was placed as the last one before placing the corresponding `\label`. Thus, with the example above, the hyperlink with `\chapref{theo}` will go to the start of the theorem in question although displaying the number of the chapter where that theorem occurs.

In case of using **hyperref**, you have "starred" variants of `\ref` and `\pageref` displaying the numbers in question but not producing a hyperlink. Therefore in case of **hyperref** being loaded there is also a "starred" variant of `\chapref`.

**!!!I have no idea whether any of these crude hacks might break functionality of whatsoever documentclass or package.!!!**

**!!!Therefore I do not give any warranties. If something breaks, handling the pieces is up to you.!!!**

**!!!The fear of breaking functionality of whatsoever documentclass or package leads me to highly recommending using the zref-package.!!!**

Comment: @ajr Never mind. I just provided my crude hack in order to fulfill your requirement of doing it without any **..ref**-package. As I pointed out in the bottom of my answer, I'd prefer using the **zref**-package. Therefore accepting another answer which - unlike my answer - also provides a solution based on **zref** is the right thing to do.  :-)