# Is there a software in Ubuntu that can analyse the cross references (theorems, lemmas, equations, etc.) in a tex project?

Tags: cross-referencing, tools, mathtools

There are some software to analyse the cross references among codes (Java or C++). I used to use a software for code analysis under Windows many years before. But I can't remember the name. On linux, an example might be LXR Cross Referencer.

Is there a similar tool that can analyse the latex files to find out the cross references of theorems, lemmas, propositions and equations?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by cross-referencing?

Comment: By cross-referencing, I mean to find out,for example, the following facts: (1) proof of Theorem 10.2 needs Lemma 10.1, Proposition 8.4 and Eq.(9.3); (2) Proposition 8.4 has been used in the proof of Theorem 10.2, Lemma 9.4 etc.

Comment: @Anand it is not customary to sign your post, I have edited and removed. :)

Comment: I can imagine doing this semiautomatically by wrapping the `\ref` macro in a macro of your own that writes the context of the reference to an external file (or saves it in an internal list). That would give the data "A uses B". Parsing/sorting that list would tell you also "B used by A".

Comment: Thanks Ethan Bolker. Do you know any implementation of these ideas?

Comment: @Anand Sorry, I don't know an implementation. I think I know enough `TeX` to write one, which I would if I needed it. But I don't, and don't have the time. Maybe one of the wizards who watch SE regularly can do it quickly.

Comment: Thanks Ethan Bolker. :-) I wish some day this tool will be available for us. :-)

Comment: An approach is given here:   http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/usage-of-table-figures-shown-in-caption/27408#27408

Comment: @Anand Do you plan to use this only for proofs?

Comment: `reftex` for `emacs` is great for tracking references across a large project provided you set up which file is the 'parent' and which ones are the 'children'.  It comes bundled as part of `AUCTeX`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Cross referencing in `LaTeX` uses quite simple schema - for every label it stores value of macro `\@currentlabel` and the page number in the aux file. There are packages, which extends this scheme, like `titleref` or `zref`, but it is still just label and some properties, which are then accessed with some form of `\ref` command.

What would be useful in this case, is something like [RDF](http://rdfabout.com/quickintro.xpd) so one can construct complex graph of objects, their properties and relationships, like

> Theorem Lorem is defined in the Section Ipsum on page 4 and it has
>   Definition foo on page 5 and Example boo on page 6, is referenced on
>   pages 3,7,89 etc...

In this model every `label` (object) can have any number of properties, which can be values, or other objects, which gives us directed graph of objects, properties and subjects. objects and properties are in form of `prefix:name`,

Now there is some simple `rdf` framework for `LaTeX`

First we define some core functions for saving and loading properties
`rdfref-core.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{rdfref-core}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\def\Nil{}%
\def\First#1#2{#1}
\def\Second#1#2{#2}

\def\parsecolon#1:#2\relax{\ifx#2\Nil\Nil\else#1\fi}%
\newcommand\RdfPrefix[1]{%
\parsecolon#1:\Nil\relax%
}
\newcommand\AddTriple[3]{%
\edef\rdf@object{#3}
\immediate\write\@auxout{\noexpand\LoadTriple{#1}{#2}{\rdf@object}}
}

\newcommand\SetProperty[3]{%
\protected@csxdef{rdf@#1@#2}{#3}%
}

\newcommand\GetProperty[2]{%
\ifcsdef{rdf@#1@#2}{%
\csuse{rdf@#1@#2}%
}{%
\PropertyNotDef{#1}{#2}%
}%
}
\newcommand\PropertyNotDef[2]{%
???%
%\typeout{rdf warning: subject #1 has no property #2}%
}

\newcommand\SubjectListAdd[2]{%
\listcsgadd{sbjlst@#1}{#2}
}
\newcommand\MapSubjectList[2]{%
\def\do##1{#2}%
\dolistcsloop{sbjlst@#1}%
}

\newcommand\PropertyListAdd[3]{%
\listcsgadd{prprtlst@#2}{{#1}{#3}}
}
\newcommand\MapPropertyList[2]{%
\def\do##1{#2}%
\dolistcsloop{prprtlst@#1}%
}


\newcommand\LoadTriple[3]{%
\SetProperty{#1}{#2}{#3}
\SubjectListAdd{#1}{#2}
\PropertyListAdd{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
```

Two useful functions are `\MapPropertyList`, which lets you to loop over all objects and subjects with given property and `\MapSubjectList` for loop over properties of given subject.

Now some helper functions, which emulates somehow latex cross-referencing system `rdfref-user.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{rdfref-user}
\RequirePackage{rdfref-core,nameref}
\newwrite\exportfile
\def\RootObject{_:doc}

\def\CurrentObject{\RootObject}

\newcommand\AddRdfType[2]{%
\def\do##1{\csgdef{rdf:type@##1}{\noexpand\unexpanded{#2}}}
%\csgdef{rdf:type@#1}{\unexpanded{#2}}
\docsvlist{#1}
}
\newcommand\AddProperty[2]{%
\AddTriple{\CurrentObject}{#1}{#2}
}


\newcommand\WithObject[2]{%
\begingroup%
\def\CurrentObject{#1}%
\def\run{#2}
\run%
\endgroup%
}



\newcommand\rdflabel[1]{%
\AddTriple{#1}{doc:hasParent}{\CurrentObject}%
\AddTriple{#1}{doc:envir}{\@currenvir}%
\def\CurrentObject{#1}%
\ifcsdef{rdf:type@\GuessRdfType{#1}}%
{\csuse{rdf:type@\GuessRdfType{#1}}}%
{\typeout{Package rdfref error: unknown type of reference #1 :\GuessRdfType{#1}:}}%
\label{#1}
}

\newcommand\GuessRdfType[1]{%
% We first try if current environment is defined as type, if not, then guess type from the parameter
\ifcsdef{rdf:type@\@currenvir}{\@currenvir}{%
\ifx\RdfPrefix{#1}\Nil\Nil\else%
\RdfPrefix{#1}%
\fi%
}%
}

\newcommand\inputontology[1]{%
\makeatletter
\input{#1}
\makeatother
}
```

command `\rdflabel` constructs `LaTeX` label, so you can use normal constructs like `\ref` and `\pageref` and creates object with some default values and then call constructor which stores properties which are defined for object of given type. Type is deducted from object's surrounding `environment`, if it doesn't have set type, it is deducted from its prefix.

These constructors are defined in ontologies, which are normal `TeX` files with macro definitions, but which must be loaded after `\begin{document}`, because they need to write to the `aux` file.

`theorem-ontology.tex`

```
\newcommand\partOf[1]{%
\AddProperty{doc:partOf}{#1}
}


\AddRdfType{Theorem}{%
\AddProperty{rdf:type}{thm:theorem}
\AddProperty{doc:pageNo}{\thepage}
\AddProperty{rdfs:label}{\@currentlabel\ \@currentlabelname}
}
\AddRdfType{thr}{%
\AddProperty{rdf:type}{thm:theorem}
\AddProperty{doc:pageNo}{\thepage}
\AddProperty{rdfs:label}{\@currentlabel\ \@currentlabelname}
}
\AddRdfType{prop}{%
\AddProperty{rdf:type}{thm:proposition}
\AddProperty{doc:pageNo}{\thepage}
\AddProperty{rdfs:label}{\@currentlabel\ \@currentlabelname}
}

\AddRdfType{lem}{%
\AddProperty{rdf:type}{thm:lemma}
\AddProperty{doc:pageNo}{\thepage}
\AddProperty{rdfs:label}{\@currentlabel\ \@currentlabelname}
}


\AddRdfType{sec}{
\AddProperty{rdf:type}{sec:sectioning}
\AddProperty{doc:pageNo}{\thepage}
\AddProperty{rdfs:label}{\@currentlabel\ \@currentlabelname}
\AddProperty{doc:label}{\@currentlabel}
}
\AddRdfType{equation}{%
\AddProperty{rdf:type}{eq:equation}
\AddProperty{doc:pageNo}{\thepage}
\AddProperty{rdfs:label}{\@currentlabel\ \@currentlabelname}
}

\WithObject{sec:sectioning}{%
\AddProperty{rdfs:label}{Sectioning}
\AddProperty{rdf:type}{rdfs:Class}
}
\WithObject{thm:theorem}{%
\AddProperty{rdfs:label}{Theorem}
\AddProperty{rdf:type}{rdfs:Class}
}
\WithObject{thm:proposition}{%
\AddProperty{rdfs:label}{Proposition}
\AddProperty{rdf:type}{rdfs:Class}
}
\WithObject{thm:lemma}{%
\AddProperty{rdfs:label}{Lemma}
\AddProperty{rdf:type}{rdfs:Class}
}

\WithObject{eq:equation}{%
\AddProperty{rdfs:label}{Equation}
\AddProperty{rdf:type}{rdfs:Class}
}
\WithObject{rdfs:Class}{%
\AddProperty{rdfs:label}{Class}
}
```

you can see that we added constructors for some environments and prefixes. important property is `rdf:type`, which can be used for example if you want to loop over all theorems or equations. there are also properties `doc:pageNo` and  `rdfs:label`, which are more or less traditional `LaTeX` cross-referencing properties. For every `rdf:object` there is also `\WithObject` macro, which set textual labels (`rdfs:label`) for these types.

there is also command `\partOf`, which declares current object as part of another object. It can be used in examples or definitions, to declare that they are part of some theorem. I do really know nothing about mathematical theorems, so this is really just an simple example, not anything useful. If you have idea about some useful properties, they can be easily added.

Now some sample file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{tgschola}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\catcode`\_=12
\usepackage[]{rdfref-user,lipsum,nameref,cleveref}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,xstring}
\declaretheorem[name=Lemma,Refname={Lemma,Lemmas}]{lem}
\declaretheorem[name=Proposition,Refname={Proposition,Proposition}]{prop}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,Refname={Theorem,Theorems}]{thr}

\begin{document}
\inputontology{theorem-ontology.tex}
\section{Hello world}\rdflabel{sec:first}
\lipsum[1-2]
  \begin{lem}\rdflabel{thm:lem1}
    \partOf{thm:thr1}
    A lemma.
  \end{lem}

  \begin{prop}
    \rdflabel{thm:prop1}
    \partOf{thm:thr1}
    A proposition.
    %\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\thecor.\arabic{enumi}}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item An item 
      \item Another one 
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{prop}

  \begin{thr}\rdflabel{thm:thr1}
    A theorem.
  \end{thr}

\begin{thr}[Euclid]
\rdflabel{thm:euclid}%
For every prime $p$, there is a prime $p’>p$.
In particular, the list of primes,
\begin{equation}\rdflabel{eq:1}
2,3,5,7,\dots
\end{equation}
is infinite.
\end{thr}

\end{document}
```

And if you want to export some graph, try this macro (Not much nice, but it shows some ways, how you can work with your properties graph):

```
\newcommand\ExportGraphviz[2]{%
digraph G\{
\forcsvlist{\listadd\typelist}{#1}
%\forcsvlist{\listadd\propertylist}{#2}
\def\worker##1##2{%
%"\ObjectLabel" -> \GetProperty{\First##1}
\edef\ppp{\GetProperty{##1}{##2}}
\typeout{Worker: ##1: ##1 : \ppp}
\IfSubStr{\ppp}{???}{}{%
"\ObjectLabel" -> %
\IfSubStr{\ppp}{:}{"\GetProperty{\GetProperty{\ppp}{rdf:type}}{rdfs:label}: \GetProperty{\ppp}{rdfs:label}"}{"\ppp"} %
%\GetProperty{##1}{##2} 
 [label="##2"];\\%
}
}
\MapPropertyList{rdf:type}{%
\xifinlist{\Second##1}{\typelist}{%
\edef\ObjectLabel{\GetProperty{\Second##1}{rdfs:label}: \GetProperty{\First##1}{rdfs:label}}%
%\ObjectLabel \& \Second##1\\}
\bgroup%
%\MapObjectList{\First##1}{}
\forcsvlist{\worker{\First##1}}{#2}%
\egroup
}%
{}%
}
\}
}
```

Because of some weird errors, I cannot do version which write to the file, so graphviz specification is simply printed to the document (really ugly, I know). It can be used in following way:

```
\ExportGraphviz{sec:sectioning,thm:theorem,eq:equation,thm:proposition,thm:proposition,thm:lemma}{doc:pageNo,doc:partOf,doc:hasParent}
```

First parameter is list of objects with given `rdf:type` which should be the exported, the second is list of properties. For some reason, on first run, when there is no aux file, it gives some errors, but after that, it should be OK

Resulting graph:

[image]

Also, it is easy using `\MapPropertyList` and `\MapSubjectList` to export data to some `rdf` serialization format, for example [turtle](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/haystack/blog/2008/11/06/a-quick-tutorial-on-the-tutrle-rdf-serialization/) and import them to some specialized `rdf` database, or visualization tool, and do many interesting things with them.

Comment: Dear michal.h21, thanks a lot for your codes. Beautifully done, although there is still some gap from the code analysis where a GUI is available with many features. I hope one day people realize the necessities of such a tool for LaTeX community and start to write one. You definitely deserve this 100 pints. Great thanks! :-)