# Create a graph of references

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a document containing references to sections (and figures and tables).

I would like to generate a graph (V,E) of the following kind. The vertices (nodes) are the sections and the v1 -> v2 is an edge if there is a reference pointing to section v2 in section v1.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171854/2891

Comment: thanks looks like what I need. I had the wrong terms when I searched for it even though it's quite simple with the proper terms... Looks a little complicated though...

Comment: yes, it is a little bit complicated, as it is only experimental package and you have to configure everything yourself

Comment: you should post some example code, so we can try some possibilities

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show graph of references inside a document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170480/show-graph-of-references-inside-a-document)