# Analysis of cross-reference/link network within a single document

Tags: hyperref

I am writing a book with several chapters and sections that are linked with each other by the use of \ref. Now I would like to get an overview of the starting points and targets of these `\ref` and `\pageref` links.

Is there a way to extract a list of `\ref` and `\pageref` including the page number of their occurrence and the page number of their target?

The data set could look as follow:

```
type, source, target
pageref, 10, 122
ref, 11, 43
```

Finally the data could be visualized in a [chord diagram](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006), so the reader would get an alternative representation on how different sections relate to each other:

[image]

Further more, it would be nice to do the same for all citations to get a glue about the amount of references per chapter/section/subsection.

**UPDATE**
So far I was playing with the following files
* .aux file: There are all \ref stored, but without any page number
* post script file: if converted to text, at least some regex could collect snippets like "see page ...". It would be helpful to process post script as human readable code.

Comment: You're taking the piss, I assume ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [rdfref](https://github.com/michal-h21/rdfref) package. It unfortunately isn't on CTAN, because it doesn't have any documentation, only an [example of usage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171854/2891).

You haven't provided any example, so I will add some:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rdfref-user,rdfref-query,nameref}
\usepackage{newfile}
\newoutputstream{references}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.ref}{references}

\begin{document}
\inputontology{theorem-ontology.tex}
\section{first}
\rdflabel{sec:first}

Some references, to section~\rdfref{sec:second} on page~\rdfpageref{sec:second}
\lipsum[1-10]

\section{second}
\rdflabel{sec:second}

Now some other references, to section~\rdfref{sec:first} on page~\rdfpageref{sec:first}

\Bind{?ref}{doc:refersTo}{?obj}{%
  \addtostream{references}{
    \GetValProperty{?ref}{rdf:type}
    \GetValProperty{?ref}{doc:pageNo}
    \GetValProperty{?obj}{doc:pageNo}
  }
}
\end{document}
```

It uses `rdfref` commands, `\rdfref`, `\rdfpageref` and `\rdflabel`, you can use something like `let\label\rdflabel` if you want to modify default LaTeX commands to use `rdfref` features.

```
\inputontology{theorem-ontology.tex}
```

loads default properties for sections and some other referenced type objects. Properties for objects are saved in the `.aux` file:

```
\relax 
\LoadTriple {sec:sectioning}{rdfs:label}{Sectioning}
\LoadTriple {sec:sectioning}{rdf:type}{rdfs:Class}
\LoadTriple {thm:theorem}{rdfs:label}{Theorem}
\LoadTriple {thm:theorem}{rdf:type}{rdfs:Class}
\LoadTriple {thm:proposition}{rdfs:label}{Proposition}
\LoadTriple {thm:proposition}{rdf:type}{rdfs:Class}
\LoadTriple {thm:proposition}{rdfs:subClassOf}{thm:theorem}
\LoadTriple {thm:lemma}{rdfs:label}{Lemma}
\LoadTriple {thm:lemma}{rdf:type}{rdfs:Class}
\LoadTriple {thm:lemma}{rdfs:subClassOf}{thm:theorem}
\LoadTriple {eq:equation}{rdfs:label}{Equation}
\LoadTriple {eq:equation}{rdf:type}{rdfs:Class}
\LoadTriple {eq:equation}{rdfs:subClassOf}{thm:theorem}
\LoadTriple {rdfs:Class}{rdfs:label}{Class}
\LoadTriple {sec:first}{doc:hasParent}{\RootObject }
\LoadTriple {sec:first}{doc:envir}{document}
\LoadTriple {sec:first}{rdf:type}{sec:sectioning}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}first}{1}}
\newlabel{sec:first}{{1}{1}{first}{}{}}
\LoadTriple {sec:first}{doc:pageNo}{1}
\LoadTriple {sec:first}{rdfs:label}{1\ first}
\LoadTriple {sec:first}{doc:label}{1}
\LoadTriple {_:blank1}{doc:hasParent}{sec:first}
\LoadTriple {_:blank1}{doc:pageNo}{1}
\LoadTriple {_:blank1}{doc:refersTo}{sec:second}
\LoadTriple {sec:second}{doc:referedBy}{_:blank1}
\LoadTriple {_:blank1}{rdfs:label}{Blank node: blank1}
\LoadTriple {_:blank1}{rdf:type}{doc:reference}
\LoadTriple {_:blank2}{doc:hasParent}{sec:first}
\LoadTriple {_:blank2}{doc:pageNo}{1}
\LoadTriple {_:blank2}{doc:refersTo}{sec:second}
\LoadTriple {sec:second}{doc:referedBy}{_:blank2}
\LoadTriple {_:blank2}{rdfs:label}{Blank node: blank2}
\LoadTriple {_:blank2}{rdf:type}{doc:pagereference}
\LoadTriple {sec:second}{doc:hasParent}{sec:first}
\LoadTriple {sec:second}{doc:envir}{document}
\LoadTriple {sec:second}{rdf:type}{sec:sectioning}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}second}{3}}
\newlabel{sec:second}{{2}{3}{second}{}{}}
\LoadTriple {sec:second}{doc:pageNo}{3}
\LoadTriple {sec:second}{rdfs:label}{2\ second}
\LoadTriple {sec:second}{doc:label}{2}
\LoadTriple {_:blank3}{doc:hasParent}{sec:second}
\LoadTriple {_:blank3}{doc:pageNo}{3}
\LoadTriple {_:blank3}{doc:refersTo}{sec:first}
\LoadTriple {sec:first}{doc:referedBy}{_:blank3}
\LoadTriple {_:blank3}{rdfs:label}{Blank node: blank3}
\LoadTriple {_:blank3}{rdf:type}{doc:reference}
\LoadTriple {_:blank4}{doc:hasParent}{sec:second}
\LoadTriple {_:blank4}{doc:pageNo}{3}
\LoadTriple {_:blank4}{doc:refersTo}{sec:first}
\LoadTriple {sec:first}{doc:referedBy}{_:blank4}
\LoadTriple {_:blank4}{rdfs:label}{Blank node: blank4}
\LoadTriple {_:blank4}{rdf:type}{doc:pagereference}
```

`\LoadTriple` has three parameters, first is an object, second is property and third value. Each `\rdflabel` produces object named as label and save some properties, such as what type it is (section, figure, etc) or page number. Each `\rdfref` and `\rdfpageref` produces so called blank node, which is anonymous object, with properties such as destination object, page number etc.

`rdfref` provides query mechanism for retrieving property values, `\Bind` command:

```
\Bind{?ref}{doc:refersTo}{?obj}{%
  \addtostream{references}{
    \GetValProperty{?ref}{rdf:type}
    \GetValProperty{?ref}{doc:pageNo}
    \GetValProperty{?obj}{doc:pageNo}
  }
}
```

It has four parameters, first three correspond to object, property, value schema, fourth is the code to be executed. Parameters which start with `?` are variables which are looked up. So in our example, we search for all objects with property `doc:refersTo`, which is automatically created for all `\rdfref` and `\rdfpageref` commands. Using `\GetValProperty` we can retrieve propery for a variable. We need to get reference type (ref or pageref) and page for reference and page number of the referenced object. These properties are then saved in file named `texfilename.ref`. It's contents for our example are:

```
 doc:reference 1 3 
 doc:pagereference 1 3 
 doc:reference 3 1 
 doc:pagereference 3 1
```

**Edit**:

regarding citations, we can utilize `biblatex` hooks and data accessing commands. Save following code as `biblatex-ontology.tex`:

```
\AddRdfType{bib}{
  \AddPropertyEx{rdf:type}{bib:bibitem}
  \AddPropertyEx{doc:pageNo}{\thepage}
  \AddPropertyEx{rdfs:label}{Bibitem: \strfield{entrykey}}
}


\WithObject{bib:bibitem}{%
  \AddProperty{rdfs:label}{Bibitem}
  \AddProperty{rdf:type}{rdfs:Class}
}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}{%
  \AtEveryBibitem{%
    \bgroup%
      \let\ParentObject\CurrentObject%
      \edef\CurrentObject{\strfield{entrykey}}%
      % save defalt properties for bib type
      \csuse{rdf:type@bib}%
      \egroup%
  }%
  \AtEveryCitekey{%
    % use default properties for referencing commands
      \rdfref@core{\strfield{entrykey}}{\AddProperty{rdf:type}{bib:citation}}%
  }
}{}
\makeatother
```

Important commands are `\AtEveryBibitem` and `\AtEveryCitekey` which saves information about bibitem and citation.

Modified document which uses `biblatex` and our new ontology:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rdfref-user,rdfref-query,nameref}
\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\newoutputstream{references}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.ref}{references}

\inputontology{theorem-ontology.tex}
\inputontology{biblatex-ontology.tex}
\begin{document}
\section{first}
\rdflabel{sec:first}

Some references, to section~\rdfref{sec:second} on page~\rdfpageref{sec:second}

Some citations: \cite{bertram}

\lipsum[1-10]

\section{second}
\rdflabel{sec:second}

Now some other references, to section~\rdfref{sec:first} on page~\rdfpageref{sec:first}

\Bind{?ref}{doc:refersTo}{?obj}{%
  \addtostream{references}{
    \GetValProperty{?ref}{rdf:type}
    \GetValProperty{?ref}{doc:pageNo}
    \GetValProperty{?obj}{doc:pageNo}
  }
}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

the `.ref` file now contains:

```
 doc:reference 1 3 
 doc:pagereference 1 3 
 bib:citation 1 3 
 doc:reference 3 1 
 doc:pagereference 3 1
```