# Library to get the struction of a latex document

Tags: luatex

> I'm looking for a library that returns a structure (perhaps OO) of a latex document.

For instance

- Chapter 1

  - Section 1.1

    - Definition 1
    - Lemma 2

      - Ref to ...
  - Section 1.2

    - Definition 3
    - Lemma 4

      - Ref to Lemma 2

My goal is a series of routines to check that

- (*) there are no references to not yet defined concepts and/or proven lemmas
- I can move a section to another chapter, or move a Lemma to another chapter without violating (*)
- a.s.o.

The tool should be able to do the job also on more books referencing to each other. I started to implement it, but there is too much work, because the needed information are scattered between the `*.tex`'s and the `*.aux`'s files.

Programming languages c++, python, java, go or similar would be good.

Tags: A set `luatex` because i'm using it and I do not find anything better.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171854/2891

Comment: @michal.h21 thank you, your rdfref is at least a perfect starting point, then I have to dump everything to a file

Comment: yes, it is best to dump everything to a file and use some simpler language than TeX to analyze the stored data