# How to automatically generate a list of all references?

Tags: cross-referencing, automation

I am finalizing a large document that contains many Propositions, Lemmas, etc. It is hard for me as an author to keep track where exactly each Proposition is being used.

It would be really helpful to be able to automatically generate a list that would say where exactly each Proposition, Definition, etc. is being referenced. What I have in mind is something like:

**Proposition 2.3.** Is Referenced in:
Lemma 3.4 on page 11.
Theorem 5.1 on page 20.
etc...

I would like to automatically generate a list whose entries look like the above example. I don't need this list to be a part of my tex file or document, rather I would like it to be generated as an external file (say text file would do).

Any ideas/suggestions, using either latex builtin capabilities or some external tool?

Thank you.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171854/2891

Comment: @michal Thank you. I will try to use this code (and come back here if I run into trouble).

Comment: the updated package code is on [Github](https://github.com/michal-h21/rdfref). Unfortunately I've never managed to write a documentation.