# Output depending on crossreferences

Tags: cross-referencing, conditionals

I want to write a specification. It has a section listing all features. Another section lists tests. Each test must reference the feature it tests.

Now by TeX-magic, I want untested features be colored red. I also want features to get a list of tests, which test it. Ideally clickable references to jump back and forth in pdfs and numbered.

More concretely, a hypothetical specification:

```
\begin{document}
\feature{Features have a List of Tests}{at-feature-list}
The first part is the title, the second a label, like for \\label
\feature{Untested Features are red}{123}
\feature{Tests link to Features they test}{crossref}

\ftest{A list of Features}{at-feature-list,123}
Create an example listing...
\end{document}
```

It should output like

```
F1. Features have a List of Tests

Tested by: T1

The first part is the title, the second a label, like for \label

F2. Untested Features are red

Tested by: T1

F3. Tests link to Features they test (colored red!)

Tested by: -

T1. A list of Features

Testing: F1, F2
```

As far as I know, there is no package for this. Implementing `\feature` and `\ftest` probably implementing something similar to `\label` and `\ref`.

Comment: this can be done using [rdfref](https://github.com/michal-h21/rdfref) package, I thing. It doesn't have documentation, unfortunately. but you can see what it can do in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171854/2891), or [another one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56394/2891)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to michal.h21 and his [rdfref package](https://github.com/michal-h21/rdfref) I was able to build something, which is nearly there.

The relevant part of the document looks like this:

```
\section*{Funktionen}

\functionality{Foo}{fnc:foo}
\functionality{Bar}{fnc:bar}

\section*{Tests}

\test{First Start}{tst:first}
\tests{fnc:bar}

\test{Trial}{tst:trial}
\tests{fnc:bar}
```

The output is:

```
Funktionen
F1 Foo   Tested by: 
F2 Bar   Tested by: T1 T2

Tests

T1 First Start   Testing: F2
T2 Trial   Testing: F2
```

The TeX macros to get there are:

```
\newcommand\tests[1]{
   \AddTripleEx{#1}{pfl:is-tested}{yeah}
   \AddProperty{pfl:tests}{#1}}
\newcommand\fulfills[1]{\AddProperty{pfl:fulfills}{#1}}

\newcommand\testlink[1]{\hyperlink{#1}%
  { \GetProperty{#1}{pfl:tstid} }}
\newcommand\functionalitylink[1]{\hyperlink{#1}%
  { \GetProperty{#1}{pfl:fncid} }}

\newcounter{functionality}
\newcounter{test}

\newcommand\functionality[2]{
  \stepcounter{functionality}
  \par\textbf{F\arabic{functionality} #1}\rdflabel{#2}
  \AddProperty{pfl:fncname}{#1}
  \AddPropertyEx{pfl:fncid}{F\arabic{functionality}}
  \IfProperty{#2}{pfl:is-fulfilled}{%
       Tested by: \Bind{?t}{pfl:tests}{#2}{ \testlink{\GetVal{?t}} }
  }{{\color{red}{NOT TESTED}}}
  \par}

\newcommand\test[2]{
  \stepcounter{test}
  \par\textbf{T\arabic{test} #1}\rdflabel{#2}
  \AddProperty{pfl:tstname}{#1}
  \AddPropertyEx{pfl:tstid}{T\arabic{test}}
  Testing: \Bind{#2}{pfl:tests}{?f}{ \functionalitylink{\GetVal{?f}} }
  \par}
```

The `\AddProperty` calls are relative to the previous `\rdflabel` and store triples like (tst:trial,pfl:tests,fnc:bar).

Then `\Bind{?t}{pfl:tests}{#2}{ \testlink{\GetVal{?t}} }` outputs the list of links. The query (?t,pfl:tests,fnc:bar) looks for all triples, where the second and third element matches. It outputs a `\testlink` for each found triple with `?t` bound to the first triple element.

There is also the (*id*,pfl:is-tested,yeah) triples. They are used for the `\IfProperty` checks. If there is no such triple for an id, then a red warning NOT TESTED is printed, instead of the backlinks.