# Create a relation graph of an existing document

Tags: table-of-contents, diagrams

I want to do the following:

Supose you have a written document, with sections, subsections, subsubsections, figures, equations, bibliography, etc. With reference among themselves.

I would like to create "in an automatic way", a graph diagram that express the relations (references) in between all the elements of the document.

I know I can use TiKz to create the graph. My question is how could I can obtain the information off all the objects and their references to draw this graph.

This document is an example of what I would like to achieve
[image: example]

Thank you !

Comment: Could you edit your post adding an MWE of your document and an image of the desired relation graph? Also a simple photo of something handwritten is enough.

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55779/2891 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170480/2891

Comment: Yeah ! That's precisely what I was looking for, thank you !