# Turning my Document into a Dependency Graph and Plotting it

Tags: graphics, packages, graphs

Often times in math, we start out with some axioms, say A,B and from those prove theorems say C. In order visualize the logical relationships, I'd like a program to distill the logical dependencies of my document into a graph (in the mathematical sense, i.e. a set of vertices and edges), and then plot the result.

In this example, the graph would be {{A,C},{B,C}}.

Is there a package that can parse through my document, distill this structure and then plot it?

If not, hopefully I can write the backend stuff to make the mathematical graph, then reformat that syntax for whatever graphics package I choose, and then send that information to the package for plotting. What packages would you recommend for plotting graphs which aren't necessarily trees?

I could also just have python parse the actual latex file and generate the structure I want, and then plot it.

Edit: In the code below, I use labels and cross-references to delineate the dependency structure.

```
\begin_body

\begin_layout Definition
A
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "def:A"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Separator plain
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Definition
B
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "def:B"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Separator plain
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Definition
C
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "def:C"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Definition
C is 
\begin_inset CommandInset ref
LatexCommand ref
reference "def:A"

\end_inset

 times 
\begin_inset CommandInset ref
LatexCommand ref
reference "def:B"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Please help us help you by showing a minimal compilable code example. Without the structure and some information how to find the dependencies in your source code we cannot do much.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56394/2891 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171854/2891 for examples

Comment: latex (unless you use some custom macros for encoding more structure) is expressing natural language text, so there is no way to derive that theorem C logically depends on theorem B without reading the text,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was thinking of using labels and cross-references to encode the dependency structure. Will edit post with an example ASAP

Comment: @EvanRosica latex is very flexible it is certainly possible to encode the dependencies, but no general parser can understand such a custom markup, you would need to extract the graph with custom code.

Comment: the document you show isn't using latex syntax at all though?

Comment: that's the .lyx file. Is there another file?

Comment: @EvanRosica sorry I have never used lyx, I did not recognise the syntax (which is totally unlike tex syntax)