# backref for tables and figures

Tags: hyperref

How to automatically locate the place referring to the table or figure when clicking the caption of table or figure, that is, backref for the table or figure. I know how to achieve this similar function for references using hyperref package.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/usage-of-table-figures-shown-in-caption

Comment: That said, the comments in the second answer to that question indicate that the functionality of the obsolete `backrefx` package has been incorporated into the `backref` package, but I don't see how `backref` quite does what you ask

Comment: Sorry for my awkward expression. I am not good at English. I wrongly think "backref" means back refer.

Comment: I fail to understand content available on the link you given. I do not know which part of Tex code achieve the function I expressed. Especially, why there are two pages of words even though there are not many entering words in Tex.

Comment: The example code in Marcol Daniel's answer uses the `lipsum` package to generate some text to fill up the document.  His final code allows you to add an `\xref` command at the end of the caption to provide backref type links.  As there may be several places in the document that link to the same table, it does not make sense to make the caption in to one single link.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I think this question deservers a standalone answer and is not a duplicate. Marco's answer specificially adds a hyperlinked pagenumber within the caption. What the OP here wants is to make the entire caption a link back to the reference. If that is good practice is another matter. Maybe he makes references only once in the text.

Comment: @Jörg I agree, this is not an exact duplicate.  What is missing in the other question is how to add backref links automatically to the caption.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).